# Git on AWS CodeCommit Bare Repository

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, version-control, aws-codecommit

I was creating my first private repository and when I was cloning I noticed that the repository that amazon created does not have a .git extension,so, it's not a bare repository? Is it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AWS CodeCommit does not store remote repositories the same way as other git hosting providers. For all intents and purposes, the remote repository can be considered a bare repository.

Comment: Can you explain a little better how they do it or point to any source? I would be very much apreciated.

Comment: The best public answer would be this question from the FAQ (http://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/faqs/): Q: How is AWS CodeCommit different from other Git-based source control systems?
Highly Available – AWS CodeCommit is built on highly scalable, redundant, and durable AWS services such as Amazon S3 and Amazon DynamoDB.