# How to clone bare repository hosted on AWS Code Commit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, git-bare, aws-codecommit

I have a repository currently being hosted on AWS Code Commit, however in console all I see is a working tree. I don't see the bare `project.git` directory I would reference when cloning the bare repo using the following:

```
git clone --bare ssh://git-codecommit.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/project.git
```

**How can I clone a bare repository hosted on AWS Code Commit? (Or where is the location of the `.git` directory?)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34666363/5031762) I can treat it as a bare repo:

`git clone --bare ssh://git-codecommit.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/project`

Simply using the `--bare` flag does the trick (no `.git` extenstion).